# saving downloads to the browser download rather than system using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a dynamic web project in my eclipse that takes an excel sheet with data and puts in a database.  Then from the database, I created a web app for the users to add, edit, delete and view the data in that database that was once on a spreadsheet.

The web app takes the data that was created, edited, deleted from the user and creates an excel spreadsheet upon the users request.  I created a link that writes the excel spreadsheet, but how would I make the new spreadsheet download to the users computer.

So if they click the link for download, it would go to the browser download, such as the browser they are using(for example in chrome), the file goes to the download bar on the bottom of the screen.  I been researching and I am just lost.  I am using java:

```
try{
   File file = new File("C:\\eclipseworkspace\\spreatdsheet.xlsx"); 

          if(file.delete()){
                    System.out.println(file.getName() + " will be overwritten, created");
                }else{
                    System.out.println(file.getName() + " does not exist.  Newly created.");
                }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile("C:\\eclipseworkspace\\spreatdsheet.xlsx"));

    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
    workbook.close();
    System.out.println("spreadsheet .xlsx was created");
```

This is the part of my java code, that imports the Apache POI classes, and writes it to the dynamic web project's directory in eclipse.

What would I have to or where would I need to start so that the spreadsheet in the directory can be downloaded into the users browser download such as chrome://downloads/ in chrome browser

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are testing this web app on the same machine as the one where you see the file into your Downloads.

You cannot write anything on the client machine from a web app. The sample code that you provide is to write a file on the server filesystem. Not the client.

What you must do is write the content of your file into the http response. If you are working with servlets it is something like

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"); // Instrcut the browser of what he will receive
    response.getOutputStream().write(/* your excel*/);
}
```

That way, the browser will download it in his default folder (that you cannot change)

Comment: Does that mean in my code, the user who visits the apps url on the server, will not be to download the excel sheet into their local drive?  Thanks

Comment: No. They will be able to download it if you write the content of your file to the http response.